# How do I intercept form creation outside of the form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to find a generic way to know when any form has been created with windows events or something of the sort. Currently I'm listening for `WM_PAINT` events within `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` and then when I detect a `Msg.hwnd` I use `FindControl()` and see if the control is `TForm`. Then I know this form is being opened and I can then do some styling that is uniform across the hundreds of forms in the application.

When I listen for `WM_CREATE` events instead I get nothing.  I'm not sure why.  I was thinking this would tell me the form has been created, but evidently it doesn't. At the moment, there are a couple of timing issues that cause only a few forms to render, and then a split second later my styling kicks in. I only find this in some cases, and the majority of the cases it works just fine. So you have the form opening up on its original styling only to have it change a split second later - in a few cases.

The moment I detect a form like this, I also reassign its `OnClose` event so that I can perform some operation when the form closes, and then I redirect it to its original `OnClose` event handler. I've tried doing the same thing with its `OnCreate` and `OnShow` events, but that doesn't fire at all this way.  The `OnClose` have been working perfectly, though.

I need my styling to kick in first before the form is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: You could inherit all forms which require this from a base form that contains the code to handle it.. else [Hook][1] TForm.loaded or CreateWnd 


  [1]: https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/DDetours

Comment: Why are you not using the VCL's own styling system? What are you trying to do exactly that is extra?

Comment: @FredS, I'm trying to avoid having to change hundreds of forms because of the size of the project.  I'll take a look at your link to see if that helps me

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find a generic way to know when any form has been created with windows events or something of the sort.

At the Win32 level, there are events related to window creation, such as:

- `SetWindowsHookEx()` hooks, such as the `HCBT_CREATEWND` notification of a `WH_CBT` hook.
- `SetWinEventHook()` events, such as `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`.

The problem with this approach is that the events are triggered after the underlying `HWND` struct has been allocated, but before it has been sent `WM_(NC)CREATE` messages.  So, for instance, calling `FindControl()` inside a handler for these events won't work, because the VCL has not yet established the link between the `HWND` and the `TForm` object.

At the VCL level, there are no global events for Form creation.  There is only the `TForm.OnCreate` event.  If you need to handle that globally for all of your Forms (or even just some of them), you should create a base `TForm` class that overrides the virtual `DoCreate()` method (and/or other virtual methods, like `CreateWnd()`, `PaintHandler()`, `WndProc()`, etc), and then derive your desired `TForm` classes from this base class.

> When I listen for `WM_CREATE` events instead I get nothing.  I'm not sure why.

`WM_CREATE` is not a *posted* message. The Win32 `CreateWindow/Ex()` API *sends* this message directly to the window's message procedure *while* creating the window. The message does not go through the creating thread's message queue, and thus will never appear in the `TApplication(Events).OnMessage` event.

> At the moment, there are a couple of timing issues that cause only a few forms to render, and then a split second later my styling kicks in. I only find this in some cases, and the majority of the cases it works just fine. So you have the form opening up on its original styling only to have it change a split second later - in a few cases.

If you are doing custom styling inside of a `WM_PAINT` handler, there should be no timing issues.

On the other hand, why are you not utilizing the VCL's built-in styling system?  For instance, you can use [`TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook) to register your own styling hook derived from `TStyleHook` for your desired classes.

Or, you could simply [define your own custom Style](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/VCL_Styles_Overview) for the VCL to use natively, no need to write any code for this.

> The moment I detect a form like this, I also reassign its `OnClose` event so that I can perform some operation when the form closes, and then I redirect it to its original `OnClose` event handler. I've tried doing the same thing with its `OnCreate` and `OnShow` events, but that doesn't fire at all this way.

Correct, because the `TForm` object has already been created and its window is visible onscreen before it receives `WM_PAINT` messages from the OS.

Comment: Thanx @remy Lebeau.  Because of hundreds of forms I've tried not to go the inheritence route.
The styling - I'm doing a couple of things.  We're using mutlitudes of dev express grids on so many forms.  So I'm setting a dev express theme this way for every grid I can find the form that opens up.  And there can be multiples of this per form.  
I'm also setting some styling related attributes for other controls, other grids too.  
I'm getting a good success rate, however I'm trying to tweak it to catch the few that are causing these flickers for when the styling kicks in just too late.